# Is it possible to inherit controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a controller that inherits from `ApiController`:

```
[RoutePrefix("v0")]
public class MyControllerV0 : ApiController {...}
```

I would like to create a new version of all the routes:

```
[RoutePrefix("v1")]
public class MyControllerV1 : MyControllerV0 {
    public MyControllerV1() : base() {}
}
```

When I add the second snippet, routes in `MyControllerV0` become inaccessible, and both prefixes causes a `404`.

Is there an additional setup piece I'm missing to achieve this, or is this not supported?

Comment: Just wondering: since you're adding routes, it shouldn't be a problem adding them to `/v0/` since it doesn't break anything. Once a breaking change is needed `/v1/` emerges, and then you'd have to define what methods you want to keep anyway. Do you want to stick with bumping the version number for every added route?

Answer (score 0):

You can have inheritance but I'm not sure about using `[RoutePrefix()]` with it.  Instead, we use full `[Route()]`.

Try this:

```
public class MyControllerV0 : ApiController {
  [Route("/api/v0/foo")]
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> V0() {

} 
}

public class MyControllerV1 : MyControllerV0 {
  [Route("/api/v1/foo")]
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> V1() {

} 
}
```

Comment: Ah I was hoping to avoid having to define all the routes again.

Comment: It is a pain to do that, but it's a one time pain, then you never need to worry about it again if you want to change just the full route for just one method.  Using the [Route()] is more explicit and easier to maintain in the future.